# How to integrate a menu in Django CMS3 and my app?

Tags: django, menu, django-cms

I have trouble setting up my menu with Django CMS 3.

I did add pages to the cms like this:

```
Home
    Teachers (id teachers)
        Contact
        Info
```

Now i can add my menu for only "teachers" like this (in my teachers/templates/teachers_index.html):

```
{% show_menu_below_id "teachers" 0 100 100 100 %}
```

In my urls.py from the main project, I have this line, so I add all the urls from the teachers app:

```
url(r'^teachers/', include('myapp.apps.teachers.urls', namespace='teachers')),
```

And in myapp.app.teachers.urls:

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
```

Now i would think all was basically set, but it is not :(

I thought an url like: teachers/contact would now go to the teachers app, but it is not. It just loads the main app template and not the one from the teachers app.

So i think i have to connect the CMS somehow to the teachers app? But i realy have no clue at all. I hope my question is clear and that someone can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, feeling stupid again... Here is how to do it:

In settings add the template:

```
CMS_TEMPLATES = (
    ('three_columns.html', 'Three columns'),    #default one
    ('teachers_index.html', 'Three columns teachers'),   #new one
)
```

and then in the CMS: edit page > advanced settings > choose template :)